# Inheriting attributes created in the parent class constructor

Tags: python, oop

I have the following parent class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, input1):
        self.input1=input1
        self.new_attrib=(self.input1)/7
```

And a child class that inherits from the parent:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, input1):
        self.input1=input1
        A.__init__(self,input1 )
    def test1(self):
         return self.new_attrib*2
```

According to OPP , could I inherit the attribute self.new_attrib from the parent class `self.new_attrib`?

from the code above it outputs: 'B' object has no attribute `new_attrib`

Then I tried `super(B, self).__init__(input1)` in the constructor of class B but arises same error

Answer (score 0):

Use super() to access the parent class

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, input1):
        self.input1=input1
    super().__init__(self,input1 )
    def test1(self):
         return super().new_attrib*2
```

Answer (score -1):

You must distinguish between `class attributes` and `instance attributes`.

In your code you create an `instance attribute` in your `__init__()` by assigning to `self`.

If you make an instance of your Class you will see, that the instance attribute is available.

```
b = B(42)
print(b.test1())
```

I think what you are checking with `B.new_attrib` is, if your `Class B` has an attribute, which checks if there are any `class attributes` which is not the case in your construct.

To create a class attribute (shared within all instances) use this:

```
def A():
   my_class_attribute = 42

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_instance_attribute = 43
```